# Search for dates on custom post types

Tags: custom-post-types

I have a custom field called date started on my custom post type, I even added a datepicker.  Now I want to search post according to some dates.  Usually I would use sql functions to find dates between some days but I have no idea how to search for a date given in a custom field.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use [WP_Query](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) for getting the posts which match your query.

And in `WP_Query` you need to use the following:

```
    'meta_query'        => array(
            'meta_key'          => 'date_started', // change it to your custom field meta_key
            'type'              => 'DATE',  // You can also try changing it to TIME or DATETIME if it doesn't work
            'meta_value'        => '2017-05-23', // Replace with your preferred value
            'meta_compare'      => '=',
),
```

Complete code would look something like:

```
<?php
$post_query = new WP_Query(
    array(
        'post_type'         => 'post',
        'posts_per_page'    => 1,
        'meta_query'        => array(
            'meta_key'          => 'date_started', // change it to your custom field meta_key
            'type'              => 'DATE',  // You can also try changing it to TIME or DATETIME if it doesn't work
            'meta_value'        => '2017-05-23', // Replace with your preferred value
            'meta_compare'      => '=',
        ),
    )
);

if($post_query->have_posts()) : while($post_query->have_posts()) : $post_query->the_post();

the_title(); // Print the title of found post

endwhile;
endif;
wp_reset_postdata();

?>
```

Comment: array(
    'key' => 'fecha_inicial', 
    'value' => $fecha, 
    'compare' => '=', 
    'type' => 'DATE' /
   ),